# NSLocalizedString is returning the key

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, internationalization, localizable.strings

In my framework app, I have some localization files added and have a method to get 
localised strings as follow

```
-(NSString *)getCurrentLocale{
    return NSLocalizedString(@"mykey", nil);
}
```

and I have installed this pod into one demo app, and trying to get the locale but it always returns the key,  (it returns 'mykey')

I have double checked the format and name `(Localizable.strings)` within the string files
all files has proper format

but I do have locale strings as values in my Localizable.strings

```
 ex:  "mykey" = "ar_SA";
```

any Idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Just wondering, why aren't you just using `Locale.current` ?

Comment: I have some requirement where my backend accepts en_us , when its actually en

Comment: BTW:  Getters should not be prefixed with `get` in objective-c.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, this happens when you don't have the Localizable.strings file in the appropriate language folder (e.g. `de.lproj`). Also, ensure you haven't put your Localizable.strings file in the `Base.lproj` folder, as the same problem will occur.

To summarize, make sure your project Localizations have their Localizable.strings files in their respective language folders to provide the correct translations.

Finally, if the above are true (and this may be obvious), the device must have its locale set to actually pull strings from a given language.

Reference: [Internationalization and Localization Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles.html)